# Adding files to Team Foundation Server from web interface

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to add a new file (or new version of a file) to a TFS project via the web interface without using Visual Studio? There are some code artifacts, such as PS1 scripts, which we may want to keep under source control, but the owners of such files may not have Visual Studio even installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this functionality is not available in TFS 2013.

This *does* exist in TFS 2015 (and in Visual Studio Online), but if you are using TFS 2013, you have a few options:

1. Install the [standalone Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40776).  Despite the name, you do not need to have Visual Studio installed - if you don't, it will install a standalone version that can communicate with a TFS server.
2. Use the command-line interface.  (Also available with the download above.)

Comment: And once you install the Team Explorer, you can download and use the [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f), which includes a Windows Explorer Shell Extension (so you can add/check in/out etc right in Windows Explorer...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. 
In our companies real world example we, have a CI build set up at work that does nothing but code sign powershell files.  This was a huge carrot to get the systems engineers to leverage source control.  The don't use Visual Studio though.  They seem to like using powerGUI which has TFS integration support.

Answer (score 0):

In the TFS 2015 web interface, yes, this is possible.

If you are asking *how*:

- To add a new file, right-click on the folder (in the folder
  hierarchy on the left) and there's a menu option to "Add file(s)...".
- To edit a file (add a version), open the file contents in the right pane, and
  there's an "Edit" button.